# Python: BeautifulSoup How to get to the sub class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape a web. Part of the code:

```
page = requests.get("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=" + str(url_id))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
raw_quality = soup.find_all(class_= 'breakdown-container quality')
print(raw_quality)
```

And for 1 url_id, as an example, I got this:

```
[<div class="breakdown-container quality">
<div>
                  Overall Quality
                  <div class="grade" title="">3.1</div>
</div>
</div>]
```

Does anyone know how I can get that '3.1' from the sub `class_='grade'`? In my case, I can't directly use `find_all(class_= 'grade')`, which will give me more mess.

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
for child in raw_quality:
    grade = child.find(class_ = 'grade').get_text()
```